# Does the GCM registration id everychange?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Does the registration id for a device - app combo ever change?  There is no mention of it's consistence in the docs (that I could find).

Also, will the same registration id be assigned to a device after an un-install and reinstall of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can change. From the doc

> Although the com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent is typically received after a request was made by the application, Google may periodically refresh the registration ID. So the application must be prepared to handle it at any time.

No, it won't be the same.

Comment: Just a note, the docs referenced above are here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html